# Transmission fails to start on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, transmission

I haven't used Transmission for a few months. Today I needed to download something and Transmission does not start (no error dialogues or exceptions are displayed in the DE). Trying it from the command line I get the following message:

```
$ transmission-gtk %U
Failed to register: Timeout was reached
```

Nothing shows up in web searches for this error message. Any ideas on what may be causing it?

Comment: have you tried opening it from the dash

Comment: why %U at the end? try running without it.  
The message seems generic one, we need real logs.

Comment: Vladimir: `transmission-gtk %U` is the command reported by Alacarte. And what do you mean by "real logs"?

Comment: I'm currently having this issue, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: If you don't want to lose your added torrents, stats, etc., you can try to copy the ~/.config/transmission to another place, remove the original one, and copy back with same name. I know it sounds weired, but it worked for me. Note you must copy it, not move to another place

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me after a very bad termination of Transmission. I couldn't get it to start no matter what selective removals I did from the config folder, but removing it altogether worked:

```
rm -r ~/.config/transmission
```

Keep in mind that this means that all configuration options, all added torrents and all stats will be deleted, and it will be as if you launched Transmission for the first time.